# download the file as attachment

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a download icon in jsp page, when i click on download icon, spring controller is called and ther i need to handle the code to download the file and save in your local machine same as downloading attachments from mail. I tried by setting "response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment;filename="abc.txt")" but could not see any option to save the file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot download a file from an HTTP server through AJAX. Instead, once you are ready, change your window location to the download link

```
window.location = contextPath + "/download.htm"; // with whatever request parameter
```

The browser will make a GET request to that location. If the response is a file download (with `content-disposition`) you'll get prompted for the target directory and your browser page won't change.